# How do I specify specific test from the build.sbt

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

How do I can specify the test from the build.sbt file , I wanted to run one test only and I used the filter as in the sbt docs, but it doesn't work with me, this is my code I have two test classes and in my sbt I specify test1 to be rub but it seems that the two test are running at the same time any one know what I should do ?

`Test1Demo.scala`

```
import org.scalatest.{FlatSpec, Matchers}

class Test1Demo extends FlatSpec with Matchers{
  "value of x " should " be 9 " in { assert(my.App.x == 9) }
}
```

`Test2Demo.scala`

```
import org.scalatest.{FlatSpec, Matchers}

class Test2Demo extends FlatSpec with Matchers{
  "value of y " should " be 8 " in { assert(my.App2.y == 8) }
}
```

`build.sbt`

```
version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.8"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.5" % Test

testOptions in Test := Seq(Tests.Filter(s => s.startsWith("Test1")))
```

the output :

```
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 2 Scala sources to /home/****/target/scala-2.12/classes ...
[info] Done compiling.
[info] Compiling 2 Scala sources to /home/****/target/scala-2.12/test-classes ...
[info] Done compiling.
[info] Test2Demo:
[info] value of y 
[info] - should be 8
[info] Test1Demo:
[info] value of x 
[info] - should be 9
[info] Run completed in 6 seconds, 365 milliseconds.
[info] Total number of tests run: 2
[info] Suites: completed 2, aborted 0
[info] Tests: succeeded 2, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
[info] All tests passed.
[success] Total time: 264 s, completed Apr 15, 2019 2:47:10 PM
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to run `value of x` test from `Test1Demo`:

```
testOnly *Test1Demo -- -z value
```

This sbt command will run only the tests whose name includes the substring "value".

For exact match rather than substring, use `-t` instead of `-z`.

Pay attention to `--` (two `-`, not one)

Comment: Thanks for answering ,but I have sbt cross compile platform and wanted to run each platform test separately E.g. I need the JVM test only not the native nor JS without using testOnly command just add some setting in my build.sbt file

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong to use filter could you correct me ?

Comment: I think you missing the `config` part. Try something like this: `lazy val FunTest = config("fun") extend(Test)

ThisBuild / organization := "com.example"
ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.12.8"
ThisBuild / version      := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

def unitFilter(name: String): Boolean = (name endsWith "Test")

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .configs(FunTest)
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies += scalatest % FunTest,
    testOptions in Test := Seq(Tests.Filter(unitFilter))
  )` . from official documentation https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Testing.html

Comment: Where I should substitute the name of test I wanted to be running ?

Comment: `name endsWith "Test1Demo"`

Comment: Really sorry I look it from the docs , however it still doesn't work with me this is the sbt :(( ````lazy val scalatest = "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.5"
lazy val FunTest = config("fun") extend(Test)
def unitFilter(name: String): Boolean = (name startsWith "Test1")
lazy val root = (project in file(".")) .configs(FunTest)
  .settings( libraryDependencies += scalatest % FunTest,
  testOptions in Test := Seq(Tests.Filter(unitFilter)) )
````
it ends with no test executed